# PHP: question about preg_replace()

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i have found this:

```
$text = preg_replace('/\W+/', '-', $text);
```

Anyone can tell me what exactly do that? There is no information about what '/\W+/' means..

Regards

Javi

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: Where have you been looking for information? The link given by sAc has plenty, as does the [PCRE manual](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt) as well as the [PHP manual](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax) as well as countless other sites taking inspiration from these and other sources.

Comment: I would also recommend taking the initiative and trying it out for yourself

Comment: don't vote a question down just because you think it's "below you." its a legitimate question, not everyone is at your level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\W` means a non-alphanumeric character, so anything other than a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or underscore.

This is standard for regular expressions, nothing specific to Php.

Here's a great tool for testing regular expressions:

http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

If you put `\W+` in the box at the top you'll see what kinds of things it matches.

PS: Here's another tool that's simpler and cleaner, though perhaps not as feature rich:

http://rubular.com/

It includes a handy quick-reference for regular expressions at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it replaces anything that isn't a 'word character' (letter, digit, underscore) and makes them hyphens.

Comment: Yep. This is kinda URLizer. So you can use the value afterwards easily in an URL. For example, if I wanted to show Thread names in the URL (SEO) I would use this regex to convert `Why doesn't this work?!?` to `Why-doesn-t-this-work-`. Here it may be seen, it's not perfect. One should at least perform a `trim($url, '-')` on it afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

The `preg` family of functions uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions, or PCRE.  There's a [nice cheat sheet for them here](http://www.phpguru.org/downloads/PCRE%20Cheat%20Sheet/PHP%20PCRE%20Cheat%20Sheet.pdf) (PDF).

The `\W` means "any non word character", and the `+` would limit it to matches of one or more of the preceding character.  "Word characters" are defined to be letters, digits and underscores, so `\W` would match characters that aren't one of those.

Your line of code would replace any occurrence of a set of characters that aren't word characters with a hyphen.

Answer (score 0):

It's documented at http://es2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php (linked from the PCRE section of the PHP manual where preg_replace is explained).